# Have Outlook search for all conversations with certain email

Tags: c#, outlook-2007

I wish to have my app initiate a search in Outlook for all mail correspondence with a certain person. I am trying to use the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook API, but I am having problems figuring out exactly how to perform this search or even if what I am attempting to do is possible.

So I do not want to extract the data from Outlook, I want to remote control Outlook to perform the search there.

Answer (score 0):

That can be done with conversations.

```
    MailItem mi = ....
    Conversation c = mi.GetConversation();
    c.GetRootItems() -->  thats the whole correspondence
```